# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Cuando trato de ejecutar una función SQL dentro de PHP surge este error:

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`db_inventory`.`vendedor`, CONSTRAINT `idCiudadVendedor` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`id_ciudad_vendedor`) REFERENCES `ciudad` (`id_ciudad`) ON DELETE NO
>   ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

Pero, si ejecuto la estructura `MYSQL` desde `phpMyAdmin` no surge problema alguno:

```
INSERT INTO `vendedor` (`id_vendedor`, `nombre_vendedor`, `documento_vendedor`, `correo_vendedor`, `telefono_vendedor`, `codigo_vendedor`, `direccion_vendedor`, `id_ciudad_vendedor`, `id_empresa_vendedor`) VALUES (NULL, 'Prueba', '222123', 'prueba@gmail.com', '3408821', 'COD0134', 'Prueba', '888', '1');
```

A continuación muestro la estructura de la tabla Vendedor.

**ESTRUCTURA SQL VENDEDOR**

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `db_inventory`.`vendedor`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `db_inventory`.`vendedor` (
  `id_vendedor`         INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre_vendedor`     VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `documento_vendedor`  VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `correo_vendedor`     VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `telefono_vendedor`   VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `codigo_vendedor`     VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `direccion_vendedor`  VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `id_ciudad_vendedor`  INT NOT NULL,
  `id_empresa_vendedor` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_vendedor`),
  INDEX `idCiudadVendedor_idx`  (`id_ciudad_vendedor` ASC),
  INDEX `idEmpresaVendedor_idx` (`id_empresa_vendedor` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `idCiudadVendedor`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_ciudad_vendedor`)
    REFERENCES `db_inventory`.`ciudad` (`id_ciudad`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `idEmpresaVendedor`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_empresa_vendedor`)
    REFERENCES `db_inventory`.`empresa` (`id_empresa`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

**ESTRUCTURA SQL CIUDAD**

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `db_inventory`.`ciudad`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `db_inventory`.`ciudad` (
  `id_ciudad`              INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre_ciudad`          VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `id_departamento_ciudad` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_ciudad`),
  INDEX `idCiudadDepartamento_idx` (`id_departamento_ciudad` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `idCiudadDepartamento`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_departamento_ciudad`)
    REFERENCES `db_inventory`.`departamento` (`id_departamento`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

**ESTRUCTURA PHP**

```
 <?php

  //Declaracion de cabeceras del sistema
  header("Context-type: application/json;");
  //Inclusion del archivo respectivo para la conexion con la BD
  require '../Connection/connection.php';
  session_start();
  //Declaracion para decodificar los datos recibidos por POST
  $_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
  //Declaracion del array para codificar en formato JSON la variable mensaje
  $resultado = array();
  //Evaluamos si la conexion a la BD se realiza correctamente
  if ($mysqli)
  {
    if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST))
    {
      //Objeto convertido a formato UTF8 para insertar caracteres especiales en la BD del sistema
      $mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
      //Capturamos los valores de las variables
      $nombreVendedor    = $_POST['nombre_vendedor'];
      $documentoVendedor = $_POST['documento_vendedor'];
      $correoVendedor    = $_POST['correo_vendedor'];
      $direccionVendedor = $_POST['direccion_vendedor'];
      $telefonoVendedor  = $_POST['telefono_vendedor'];
      $codigoVendedor    = $_POST['codigo_vendedor'];
      $ciudadVendedor    = $_POST['ciudad_vendedor'];
      $idEmpresa = $_SESSION['usuario']['id_empresa'];
      /*
        echo "Nombre: " . $nombreVendedor;
        echo "Documento: " . $documentoVendedor;
        echo "Correo: " . $correoVendedor;
        echo "Direccion: " . $direccionVendedor;
        echo "Telefono: " . $telefonoVendedor;
        echo "Codigo: " . $codigoVendedor;
        echo "Ciudad: " . $ciudadVendedor;
        echo "ID: " . $idEmpresa;
      */

      //Prepramos la consulta para INSERTAR datos en la Base de Datos a la tabla VENDEDOR
      $consulta_sql = "INSERT INTO `vendedor` (`id_vendedor`, `nombre_vendedor`, `documento_vendedor`, `correo_vendedor`, `telefono_vendedor`, `codigo_vendedor`, `direccion_vendedor`, `id_ciudad_vendedor`, `id_empresa_vendedor`)
                       VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";


      $insertar_vendedor = $mysqli->prepare($consulta_sql);
      echo "Echo consulta: " . "$consulta_sql";
      //Usamos el metodo bind_param() para captar las variables en la Base de Datos
      /*
         *Las 'ssssssii' representan el tipo de dato
      */
      $insertar_vendedor->bind_param('ssssssii', $nombreVendedor,
                                                 $documentoVendedor,
                                                 $correoVendedor,
                                                 $telefonoVendedor,
                                                 $codigoVendedor,
                                                 $direccionVendedor,
                                                 $ciudadVendedor,
                                                 $idEmpresa);

      //Ejecutamos la consulta
      if ($insertar_vendedor->execute())
      {
        /*
           *Verificamos si hubo filas afectadas
           *y decidimos el estado del mensaje con un operador ternario
        */
        $insertedRows = $insertar_vendedor->affected_rows;
        $mensaje = ($insertedRows > 0) ? "Se ha registrado correctamente el vendedor." : "No fue posible realizar el registro del vendedor, vuelve a intentarlo más tarde. " . $insertar_vendedor->error;
        $resultado['mensaje'] = $mensaje;
      }
      else
      {
        $resultado['mensaje'] = "Ha ocurrido un error importante al tratar de ejecutar el SCRIPT: " . $mysqli->error;
        // . $mysqli->error
      }
    }
    else
    {
      $resultado['mensaje'] = "La petición con el respectivo método POST es inapropiado para la URL visitada.";
    }
  }
  else
  {
      $resultado['mensaje'] = "No se ha podido establecer la conexion.";
  }
  echo json_encode($resultado);
 ?>
```

Cabe resaltar que la tabla Hija que en este caso seria `ciudad` contiene valores en su respectivos campos. Por lo que descarto esta opción:

> Esto puede ocurrir por lo que ya se ha comentado: hay entre las dos
>   tablas algún dato que quedaría huérfano al no existir en la otra
>   tabla.

Además de que se puede ejecutar correctamente desde el gestor de MYSQL, por lo que me parece muy raro. por lo que me gustaría saber el ¿por qué puede suceder esto?

> **Nota:** Se que puede ser considerada como duplicada pero, de todas las preguntas que vi al respecto no encontré el por que se puede
>   ejecutar correctamente en el gestor y no con el Script de PHP.

Comment: Agrega la estructura de la tabla ciudad.

Comment: Por favor, imprime como queda el query dentro de php, asi podemos comparar que relmente son el mismo. Ademas, asegurate que en los dos casos te estas conectando a la misma base de datos!

Comment: @alanfcm ya he añadido la estructura de la tabla Ciudad.

Comment: @gbianchi, he actualizado el codigo de PHP, no lo habia puesto para no extenderlo demasiado.

Comment: por favor, hace un echo de tu query dentro de php. Quiero controlar que sean EXACTAMENTE iguales

Comment: @gbianchi  echo consulta: INSERT INTO `vendedor` (`id_vendedor`, `nombre_vendedor`, `documento_vendedor`, `correo_vendedor`, `telefono_vendedor`, `codigo_vendedor`, `direccion_vendedor`, `id_ciudad_vendedor`, `id_empresa_vendedor`)\r\n                       VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Comment: Compara este `$ciudadVendedor` numero el `id_ciudad` de la tabla **ciudad**

Comment: @srJJ le he hecho seguimiento a cada una de las variables hasta que las capturo con PHP, por lo que todo hasta aqui esta correcto. Cada valor corresponde al esperado.

Comment: pero.. en el php que esta aca, en la pregunta, no figura id_vendedor...

Comment: @gbianchi Si, es que estaba probando si eso podría generar el error, pero sigue igual.

Comment: Bueno.. yo me estaba guiando por eso mismo. por favor, arregla la pregunta y que quede exactamente como tenes el codigo. tambien deberias imprimir los parametros, para ver que realmente esten llegando como corresponde

Comment: Ahi lo corregí, tal cual como está. También he verificado cada uno de los valores que envio (todos estan capturados de la forma esperada), tanto el `id_ciudad` que me retorna un valor `888` que en la BD es la ciudad Pereira. Ademas, he encontrado un patron que al momento de realizar un registro en la BD el id del vendedor se incrementa asi no haya sido exitoso (aunque no hay registros de ello).

Comment: pon el var dump de tus variables para más información

Comment: ¿El error ocurre intentando insertar un sólo valor o intentando insertar varios valores al mismo tiempo?  Si es un sólo valor y dices que funciona al probarlo directamente en la interfaz gráfica (con los mismos datos supongo), se me ocurren dos posibles causas: 1. que en PHP algún valor no se está recogiendo adecuadamente (supongo que habrás depurado cada valor, hazlo con `var_dump`, que te dirá la longitud de  las cadenas, a veces traen espacios de más y cosas así); 2. que desde PHP estás conectado a otra tabla/base de datos cuyos datos están incompletos.

Comment: @A.Cedano tenías razón, resulta que cuando capturaba las variables desde Angular les estaba agregando dos caracteres a su longitud a cada una de las variables, por lo que al momento de ingresarlo no coincidia con los valores de la tabla Ciudad, lo raro es que cuando las veía con el `echo` de PHP mostraba correctamente el valor esperado, hasta que usé el `var_dump`.... Gracias, como siempre por darme una nueva perspectiva.

Comment: De nada. Siempre es conveniente *limpiar* los datos antes de insertarlos, aplicando funciones como `trim` o, preferiblemente una función más trabajada que quite no solamente los espacios de más, sino también los dobles espacios en blanco, etc.